# Protect data while sending to third party back end

Tags: http-post

On my ecommerce website, I am trying to implement exchange feature. The backend is done Cashify API. I take details of new item and exchange item and send that to Cashify.

My request is being intercepted and data being changed before sending to Cashify.

I thought of encrypting the data, but then I have send across the encryption key to Cashify to get the value decrypted.

Comment: This is what TLS is meant for, ie as used in HTTPS (aka HTTP over TLS).  Use TLS to encrypt your connections, and to protect transmitted data from being tampered with. Honestly, any eCommerce site that is NOT using TLS to protect its customer data is not worth doing business with.

Comment: The person is using chrome developer tool to internet and  change the request payload. Will TLS solve this issue? @RemyLebeau

Comment: What you describe makes no sense. A browser's dev tools can only see data the browser itself transmits to a server. What the server does on its end cant be seen by the tools. TLS will only protect what is transmitted. If a user is altering data inside the browser before its even transmitted to your server, there is nothing you can do about that. Once the data arrives in your server, it is your responsibility to keep it protected when forwarding it to Cashify.